# Invalid size 1 with strtok

Tags: c

I tried to create word parser for a project, when I use strtok I get from Valgrind invalid size 1, says that the address is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
here is my code

```
  TextNode * wordParser(char * line) /* parser according to :, $ */
{
    TextNode * par;
    TextNode * firstNode;
    firstNode = createNode(strlen(line) + 1);
    par = firstNode;
    par->val = strtok(line, " :,$");

    if(par->val == NULL)
    {
        printf("NULL\n");
       

        return 0;
    }
    par->nodeSize++;
   
    while(par->val != NULL)
    {
        
        TextNode  * nextNode = createNode(MAX_LABEL_LEN);
        par->nodeSize++;
        par->nextNode = nextNode;
        par = par->nextNode;
        par->val = strtok(NULL, " :,$");
    }

  
    return firstNode;
}
```

this is createNode

```
TextNode * createNode(int strLen)
{
    TextNode * node = (TextNode*)malloc(sizeof(TextNode));
    node->val = NULL;
    node->nextNode = NULL;
    node->nodeSize = 0;

    return node;
}
```

Comment: What is `line`?  Where does it come from?  And what is the point of the `strLen` argument to `createNode`?  It isn't used at all.

Comment: Could you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Note that `strtok` doesn't return a copy, but a pointer into the buffer at `line` (a buffer it modifies). So if you free that buffer or edit it, you invalidate your data structure. This is perhaps the underlying cause of the problem.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.